# Allow Class and its Subclasses as type

Tags: node.js, typescript

This Discount class I wrote only seems to allow `Product` but not its subclasses like: `Beverage` how do I achieve that?

```
class Discount {
    constructor(type: Product, quantity: number){}
}

new Discount(Product, 23) // works
new Discount(Beverage, 12) // does not work
```

This is how I constructed the classes:

```
interface ProductInterface {
    value(): number;
}  

class Product implements ProductInterface{
    value(): number {
        throw 'Not Implemented'
    }
}

class Beverage extends Product {
    value(): number {
        return 50;
    }
}
```

(By the way would you have constructed this classes in TS differently?)

Comment: `Product` and `Type` are the classes/constructors, shouldn't it be `new Discount(new Beverage(), 12)`?

Comment: This is not really reproducable: https://tsplay.dev/WG4rVw

Comment: Hi @TobiasS. you are right. Thank you. Somehow when I run jest I get the error: `Type 'Beverage' provides no match for the signature '<T extends Product>(): any'.`. But this seems to be something different.

Comment: @MoritzRingler and TobiasS. big thanks again. Looks like it was something jest related. Somehow works now.